# setting jQuery .data() within .getJSON callback

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm doing a couple of .getJSON calls and if any one of them succeeds, I'm trying to set a bool to true so I can then do some other stuff elsewhere on the page.  I was trying to use jquery's .data() function, but I don't seem able to set it from inside the .getJSON callback.  for example:

```
$('#citations_button').data('citations', false);

$.getJSON(apaurl, function(data) {
    $('#apacite').html("<td class=\"bibInfoLabel\">APA Citation</td><td class=\"bibInfoData\">"+data+"</td>");
    $('#citations_button').data('citations', true);
}, "html");

// other .getJSONs look like above...

console.log("citations? "+$('#citations_button').data('citations'));
```

prints false, even when I know the data came through.  I thought this would work since .data() uses the cache to store the key/value pair.  how can i flag successes??  appreciate any assistance!!

Comment: `getJSON` is an async call, are you sure it returns before your call call to `console.log`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to keep in mind the sequence in which your code is actually run. Your code will actually run in the following order:

```
$('#citations_button').data('citations', false);
$.getJSON(apaurl, ..., "html");
console.log("citations? "+$('#citations_button').data('citations'));
```

Then, eventually, when the asynchronous request comes back, it will run your callback function:

```
$('#apacite').html("<td class=\"bibInfoLabel\">APA Citation</td><td class=\"bibInfoData\">"+data+"</td>");
$('#citations_button').data('citations', true);
```

Sure, you **eventually** set `citations` to be `true`, but not until long after you've already printed its `false` value out to the console.

If you want to do something only after you've gotten your JSON data, that code absolutely **must** be in that callback function (or must be called from within that callback function, of course).

If you need to wait for a result from *all* the calls, you can do something like this:

```
var expectedResponses = 2;

function gotResponsesFromAllCalls() {
    // Do things you can only do when ALL calls have returned.
};
$.getJSON(url1, function(data) {
    // Do things specific to the return of URL 1
    if (--expectedResponses == 0)
        gotResponsesFromAllCalls(); 
}, "html");

$.getJSON(url2, function(data) {
    // Do things specific to the return of URL 2
    if (--expectedResponses == 0)
        gotResponsesFromAllCalls(); 
}, "html");
```

Comment: This is very helpful.  So is there some other way to achieve my goal?  Could I group all my .getJSON calls somehow and then run some code once they've all returned?  thanks!

Comment: (in my case, i need at least one response so i will set the counter to 1 and as soon as it hits zero i can execute the gotResponses function)

Comment: If you need only one response, there's no need for a counter — just call the same function from each callback.

Comment: but then if they all succeed, i will be calling the function unnecessarily, right?

Comment: That's a fair point. Yes, in that case a counter mechanism can still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Put what you describe as 'do some other stuff elsewhere on the page' in a function.  Call that function in the $.getJSON() callback